# What is appositive and modifier?

Tags: word-choice, difference, terminology

I always get stuck between ***appositive*** and ***modifier***. As first learner in writing, I need to distinguish them. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

The appositive is a noun or noun phrase that modifies another noun. The appositive follows directly after the noun, with a comma separating them. It is similar in *placement and intent* to the reflexive.

Examples:

> The *tree*, an **oak**, cast a long shadow at sunset.
>
> The *tree*, an **old oak**, cast a long shadow at sunset.
>
> The *tree*, an **old knotted oak**, cast a long shadow at sunset

Opposite the appositive, modifiers tend to come *before* the noun(s) they modify. Let's use the above example:

> The **old knotted oak** *tree* cast a long shadow at sunset.

Comment: An appositive is not a modifier at all. It is a clarification of the noun to its left.

Answer (score 0):

***Appositive*** and ***Modifiers*** are two completely different elements that function in very different ways. *Modifiers* can occur in phrase structure, or they can be used to modify clauses. But an *Appositive* can never occur in Phrase structure, except in some cases where there is no comma before it.

Here is an example of an Appositive:

> Yesterday I watched the opera 'Carmen'.

In most cases the Appositive is detached from a phrase with a comma:

> My cat, Tom, is very naughty.

Here notice that *my cat* and *Tom* both refer to the same entity. And you can use either *Tom* or *my cat* without changing the meaning of the sentence.

> My cat is very naughty = Tom is very naughty.

Here *Tom* is the Appositive.

Now consider the following sentence:

> [The alarming fact that the ice is melting rapidly] is a cause of concern for the scientists.

The bracketed element – *the alarming fact that the ice is melting rapidly* – is a Noun Phrase (NP) that functions as the Subject (Complement) of the clause.

Let's analyze the NP structure. The head noun here is *fact*.  *The* (WORD-CLASS: *determinative*) is a Determiner, and *alarming* (WORD-CLASS: *adjective*) is a Modifier. We can omit Modifiers like *alarming* without making the sentence ungrammatical in most cases. But of course the meaning might be affected.

The Complement of the head noun is *that the ice is melting rapidly* and in most cases it can't be omitted without making the sentence ungrammatical.  Likewise, we can't omit the Determiner *the* because *fact* is a count noun.

Comment: I edited this answer somewhat.  I think the first paragraph still needs editing, because in H&P's theoretical framework Appositive dependents are actually a specific kind of Modifier and can occur in NP structure (see CGEL p.447), although they are rather different from non-appositive Modifiers.