# Can an identifying clause placed at the end of the sentence?

Tags: relative-clauses

> REPORTER: The DEA is mourning Jack Weber this evening, **a 20-year
>   forensic investigator for the agency in Miami**.

In above sentence, an identifying clause placed at the end of the sentence. Is that grammatical correct ?

I find these lines in *Bad Boys for Life 2020*

Comment: I think it's stylistically a bit weak, because the adverbial element ***this evening*** doesn't really sit well between "Jack Weber" and what you're calling the "identifying clause" (maybe that's the correct terminology here, i dunno). I'd prefer to move it, as for example *The DEA is **this evening** mourning Jack Weber, a 20-year forensic investigator for the agency in Miami.*

Comment: ...the element ***a 20-year forensic investigator for the agency in Miami*** is an [***appositive***](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/75174/what-is-appositive-and-modifier) . From that link, another example would be *Yesterday I watched the opera 'Carmen'* Note that it would ***not*** be "valid" (syntactically? idiomatically?) to relocate that adverbial element, as *I watched the opera yesterday 'Carmen'*, which is effectively what your cited example is doing.